# How to build app Twitter using Retrofit?

Tags: twitter, retrofit

I need to help. I'm doing a project about Twitter, but I don't know how to build it by using Retrofit. I really need some documents or an available one to make a reference.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in a complete tutorial for retrofit, I suggest you read the whole tutorial before you start working on the Twitter example, good luck:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#exercise-using-retrofit-with-oauth-to-request-user-details-from-twitter-in-android